# Is there a way to change the sorter icon in sapui?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am using sapui5 to create a table. I was wondering if I could change the default icon of the sort ascending and the sort descending to my own icons?

Additional question:
Is there a way to show my custom icon in the header without having to click on it first?

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the table? Is it an export of some kind?

Comment: It's a table like the one created here: [http://jsbin.com/fohizi/2/edit?html,output](http://jsbin.com/fohizi/2/edit?html,output)

Comment: edited my answer with the answer for the add. question

Comment: @Anthony was the answer correct? If so mark it as answered so others know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check your table in the Web-Developer Tools and hover over the icon in your page.
You should find something like this:

[image: the img tag]

with this you can then take the link and follow it in your system and replace it. If I find a faster way to replace it through coding, I will edit this post.

Additional Question: Yes it is possible, but only if you choose to filter that one column from the start for example:

```
var oColumn = new sap.ui.table.Column({
    label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Last Name"}),
    template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "lastName"),
    sortProperty: "lastName",
    filterProperty: "lastName",
    width: "200px"
});

//Initially sort the table
oTable.sort(oTable.getColumns()[0]);
```

Define how to sort the Column and the define the number of the column with `oTable.getColumns()[0]`, the 0 is the first row (In JavaScript arrays start with 0).

Comment: I tried to change the icon from the web developer page to see if it would work but when I click on the icon it just goes back to the original code. Is there anyway to open the sapUiTheme in visual studio? Or do I just copy it from the web developer page to overwrite it?

Comment: I guess the `:hover` attribute and `:active` have a link to other icons, which you have to change. I am not sure if it works in Visual studio, you will have to try.

Comment: Sorry I couldnt be more of a help :)